# Trivial indefinite integral with roots - can you spot the mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

**Apparently my result is correct. Nevertheless, can someone take a look at the final expression and judge if the absolute values inside logarithm have been correctly reduced?**

Can anybody spot the mistake? I have no idea where it is... And it is very trivial example...

$\gamma = \int \frac{\sqrt{x}+4}{x\sqrt{x} - x}dx = \Bigg(\Bigg( t = \sqrt{x}, t^2=x, 2tdt=dx \Bigg)\Bigg) = 2\int\frac{(t+4)tdt}{t^3-t^2} = 2\int\frac{t+4}{t^2-t}dt = \int\frac{2t+8}{t(t-1)}dt = \gamma$

Partial fraction decomposition:

$\Rightarrow \frac{2t+8}{t(t-1)} = \frac{A}{t} + \frac{B}{t-1}$

$2t + 8 = A(t-1) + Bt$

$2t+8=At - A + Bt$

$2 = A + B \quad \land \quad 8 = -A$

$\Longrightarrow A = -8 \quad \land \quad B = 10$

$\gamma = -8\int\frac{dt}{t} + 10\frac{dt}{t-1} = -8\ln{|t| + 10\ln{|t-1|} + C}$

After substitution:

$\gamma = -8\ln|\sqrt{x}| + 10\ln{|\sqrt{x} - 1|} = \ln{\frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)^{10}}{x^4}} + C$

**Two questions:**

- where's the mistake? I cannot seem to find it, wolframalpha says the result is wrong
- let's assume that the result is good (it is not, but let's assume). Can someone look at the very final result and tell me if the absolute values inside natural logarithm were reduced in a good way, or I missed some absolute values in there?

Thanks

Comment: I guess the $x\sqrt{x}$ has to be treated as $x^{\frac{3}{2}}$, and I failed at the very beggining? Still, can someone take a look at my second question? :)

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+(sqrt(x)%2B4)%2F(x%5E(3%2F2)-x)+dx) agrees with your solution. You should provide a link for questions like this; it is highly probable you simply made a typo on WolframAlpha's website or that WolframAlpha's solution is equivalent to yours after some algebraic manipulations (although, the link I provide has very minimal simplifications compared to your answer).

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+of+-8ln(sqrt(x))+%2B+10ln(sqrt(x)-1)
I took the derivative of the result and I thought it was different solution. D:

Comment: The only difference is a negative sign in front of the fraction, which is accounted for by the terms in the denominator being in reverse order. Furthermore, if you scroll down the page and look at the "Alternate Forms" and "Expanded Forms" you'll actually see the result precisely as your integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+(sqrt(x)%2B4)%2F(x%5E(3%2F2)-x)+dx) does, in fact, agree with your answer.

As far as considering the absolute values for your answer: with your simplification, your result remains equivalent. In particular, we have $$|\sqrt{x}-1|^{10}=(\sqrt{x}-1)^{10},\qquad |x|^4=x^4.$$
This is because the base has been raised to an even exponent; for any $y\in\Bbb R$, we have $y^{2k}\geq0$ for $k\in\Bbb N$.